# Prevent elements from zooming off screen

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a row of three thumbs (.img).

When I img:hover, the image zooms and enlarge by 2.0 which forces the image on the left and right to be shifted off screen.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my current code:

```
.img:hover{
    transition: .3s ease;
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(1.55);
    z-index:99;
    align-content:center;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This does not happen with a simple example of 3 imgs in a row plus your CSS. Could you put up a snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: This does happen. For example, there are three columns with 1 image in each. Each image expands upon hover. The image on the left would expand so that the left 200px is now off the screen. The image on the right would expand so that the right 200px is now off the screen. 

Ideally, I want the hover to move the picture to the center of the screen.

Comment: Hi, I'm not saying you aren't seeing the phenomenon, only that in the simple case I tried it does not happen. We need to see your HTML structure as well as your CSS. Please put up a snippet else we can't help.